# Element Tree (Python) itertext not working with line breaks

Tags: python, xml-parsing

As a followup question to one I recently posted ...

I am doing some XML parsing with ElementTree, and I have the following method in Python:

```
def extract_all_text(element):
  "".join(element.itertext())
```

The purpose of this is to extract the text from an element, stripping any tags wrapping any text in the element. ėg., `extract_all_text(ElementTree.fromstring('<a>B <c>D</c></a>'))` should return `B D`. However, I'm getting a strange error trying to use this method with elements from files containing line breaks. The error looks like this:

```
File "/home/Intredasting/foo.py", line 74, in bar
  description = extract_all_text(root.find('description')).strip()
File "/home/Intredasting/foo.py", line 62, in extract_all_text
  return "".join(element.itertext())
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

If I run `ElementTree.dump(root.find('description'))`, which shows the XML element that I am trying to parse, I get this:

```
<description>
  Foo <a href="http://example.com">bar</a>.
</description>
```

If I remove the line breaks by editing the file so that the element looks like this:

```
<description>Foo <a href="http://example.com">bar</a>.</description>
```

then the method works perfectly and I get `Foo bar.`. Why does this happen? How can I get the method to work with line breaks?

**EDIT**:

You can see the specific file I am using here (I whittled it down to a simple version, but it still causes the error): http://www.filedropper.com/example_1

To test this file, try

```
$ python3
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('/path/to/example.xml')
>>> desc = tree.getroot().find('description')
>>> print("".join(desc.itertext()))
```

(This should yield the error.)

**ANOTHER EDIT**:

This code provides additional insight into what is happening (run this in addition to the above code)

```
>>> for text in desc.itertext(): print(text)
['\n', '    Foo ']
bar
['.', '\n', '  ']
```

Of course, I can get around this issue by simply joining those lists together into a string. But I feel like this is either a bug with ElementTree, or something's funky with the input file, or my version of Python is screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

Can't duplicate your result using Python 2.7.5 and ElementTree 1.3.0

```
In [1]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

In [2]: ET.VERSION
Out[2]: '1.3.0'

In [3]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:el = ET.fromstring("""<description>
:        Foo <a href="http://example.com">bar</a>.
:    </description>""")
:--

In [4]: "".join(el.itertext())
Out[4]: '\n        Foo bar.\n    '
```

What version of Python and ElementTree are you using? If you are using Python 3.3+ it might be related to this bug http://bugs.python.org/issue16913 (*fixed in 3.3.1*)

**EDIT**

I tried your code (*print should be function btw*) in Python 3.3.2+ and can't reproduce the bug but Python 3.3.0 gives the same error message. I'd say it's an ElementTree issue.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.3, and I'm not using HTML entities. I will post the actual file soon

Comment: I just got around to posting the file (please see above)